# How to make a ajax div just text?

Tags: ajax

I wish to make this line  `$(".load-more").text("No more.");` text only not clickable link like load more.

How can I get that to happen if someone could help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Load more data
    $('.load-more').click(function(){
        var row = Number($('#row').val());
        var catid = Number($('#catid').val());
        var allcount = Number($('#all').val());
        row = row + <?php echo $records_per_page; ?>;
        if(row <= allcount){
           $("#row").val(row);
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo DIR; ?>getCat.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {row:row,catid:catid},
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $(".load-more").text("Loading...");
                },
                success: function(response){
                    // Setting little delay while displaying new content
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // appending posts after last post with class="post"
                        $(".post:last").after(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
                        var rowno = row + <?php echo $records_per_page; ?>;
                        // checking row value is greater than allcount or not
                        if(rowno > allcount){

                            // Change the text and background
                             $(".load-more").text("No more.");
                            $('.load-more').css("background","#FB0925");
                        }else{
                            $(".load-more").text("Load more.");
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('.load-more').text("Loading...");
            // Setting little delay while removing contents
            setTimeout(function() {
                // When row is greater than allcount then remove all class='post' element after 3 element
                $('.post:nth-child(3)').nextAll('.post').remove().fadeIn("slow");
                // Reset the value of row
                $("#row").val(0);
                // Change the text and background
                $('.load-more').text("Load more");
                $('.load-more').css("background","#333333");
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I am not too familiar with ajax so hope you guys do not mind helping out in it.

thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML that goes with this so we can better answer the question. That said, assuming your load more button is wrapped in a link, probably will be interested in jQuery's [`.unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/). So your code would just be `$('.load-more').unwrap().text('No more.');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after

```
$(".load-more").text("No more.");
```

put this:

```
$('.load-more').css( 'pointer-events', 'none' );
$('.load-more').click(function(){return false;});
```